# Creating reference to ImageView causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, crash, imageview

I am creating a splash screen (in .jpg format) which fills the whole screen and that when pressed starts a new `Activity`.
My problem is now that the app crashes when I reference the ImageView.

My Welcomescreen.java class:

```java
public class Welcomescreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView wd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //PROGRAMM CRASHES IN THIS LINE
    wd = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.lwd);   

    // Fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);

    // when Image is clicked
    wd.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcomescreen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.lwd:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.tm.talesof.MENU"));
        break;
    }
}

}
```

And here is my .xml File:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Welcomescreen">

<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/smalltest"
    android:id="@+id/lwd"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app crashes at the commented line in the .java class. If I delete the line everything is fine but no image is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your LogCat errors, but you must call `setContentView()` *before* `findViewById()`:

```
// Fullscreen
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);
wd = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.lwd);
```

I'm not sure why it would crash were you indicated but I do know it would crash in `onCreate()` the first time you referenced your ImageView `wd.setOnClickListener(this)`.

Comment: Your answer was totally right and it seems quite logic but I never read something about the order. Thanks for that ultrafast and precise answer!

Comment: No trouble, it is a common error while people are learning Android. The documentation for `findViewById()` should be more explicit...